# Can I take knitting needles through security in Zaventem airport?

Tags: airport-security, bru

I know TSA allows knitting needles and many airports in the world follow that. I've heard various conflicting reports on whether they allow knitting needles in carry-on or not. I found a tweet by the airport saying that they are not allowed but crochet hooks are. Is that the case?

The Twitter app on my phone doesn't allow me to copy the link, it seems. Feel free to edit the link in and remove this text.

Answer (score 1):

No, seems to be the answer.

The [Brussels Airport security information](http://www.brusselsairport.be/en/passngr/security/prohibited_items/), while not specifically mentioning knitting needles, has this to say about pointy things (emphasis mine):

> **In your hold baggage**
>
> The following items are allowed in your hold baggage (**not in your hand baggage**)
>
> - Pointed and/or sharp objects (scissors, knives, ski and walking poles, darts, ...)

I have located the tweet to which I believe you're referring, 23 Dec 2013 to @BrusselsAirport

> Are knitting needles allowed in the carry-on luggage (Schengen flight)? My wife wonders if she can knit while on board.

Which received this response from the verified account ‏@BrusselsAirport

> Hello, knitting needles are unfortunately not allowed as hand luggage. *CW